# Hibernate one to many mapping mapped by criteria

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

Can two tables be mapped by based on 2 columns.

I have table A and B

A and B both has columns `id` and `status`.

I want to get records that matches both columns in both tables.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use a join ?

Here is an example:

```
SELECT A.*, B.* 
FROM A 
INNER JOIN B ON A.id = B.id and A.status = B.status
```